# ADO.Net connection executing DB2 stored procedure returning pooled output parameter values using iSeries connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ado.net, db2, connection-pooling

***[EDIT - This issue is resolved.  The problem had to do with uninitialized out parameters on the stored procedure.]***

Why would I need to turn connection pooling off to get this to work correctly???
***[EDIT - connection pooling released a shared connection memory area on the AS400]***

In my MVC web app I call a DB2 Stored Procedure (SP).
This SP has multiple in and out parameters similar to this pseudo code:

```
CreatePO(@REQNO[in], @PO[out], @Approver[out], @ErrorMsg[out])
```

My app writes data to tables used by this SP during its processing so when all the data is in place I call the SP and it tries to create a PO.

If the PO creation fails there will be an error message in the @ErrorMsg out parameter.  In these cases the @PO and @Approver parameters should be blank.

Here's what happens in sequence:

1)  I try to create my first PO but there is a problem...
   CreatePO(100, blank, blank, blank) 
  *which results in...*
   CreatePO(100, blank, blank, 'unable to determine approver')

2)  I successfully create the 2nd PO...
CreatePO(101, blank, blank, blank)
CreatePO(101, 'P1234', 'JJONES', blank)

3)  I try to re-create a PO for @REQNO 100
    CreatePO(100, blank, blank, blank) 
    CreatePO(100, 'P1234', 'JJONES', 'unable to determine approver')

Step 3 has conflicting out parameters.  The app pool is returning the PO and Approver from Step 2 along with the appropriate an error message.

**If I recycle my IIS app pool then the results are back to what happened in Step #1.**

I am able to get expected results I add "pooling=false" to the connection string.  But **why would output parameters be affected in this manner by connection pooling?**  This seems more like a bug than some sort of desirable caching method.

If I don't paste my code someone will get bent out of shape so here it is...

(Look at the end of the top two lines)

```
    'Dim cs As String = "DataSource=mydb;UserID=myuser;Password=mypassword;Naming=System;ConnectionTimeout=180; DefaultIsolationLevel=ReadUncommitted;AllowUnsupportedChar=True;CharBitDataAsString=True; TransactionCompletionTimeout=0;pooling=false"
    Dim cs As String = "DataSource=mydb;UserID=myuser;Password=mypassword;Naming=System;ConnectionTimeout=180; DefaultIsolationLevel=ReadUncommitted;AllowUnsupportedChar=True;CharBitDataAsString=True; TransactionCompletionTimeout=0;"
    Using conn As New iDB2Connection(cs) 
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As iDB2Command = New iDB2Command()
        cmd.Connection = conn 

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "BF6360CL"

        ' Input parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New iDB2Parameter With {.ParameterName = "@REQNO", .DbType = SqlDbType.Char, .Size = 7, .Value = model.RO})

        ' Output parameters
        Dim opo = New iDB2Parameter With {.ParameterName = "@POORDER", .DbType = SqlDbType.Char, .Size = 7, .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(opo)

        Dim oApprover = New iDB2Parameter With {.ParameterName = "@APPROVER", .DbType = SqlDbType.Char, .Size = 10, .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(oApprover)

        Dim oStatus = New iDB2Parameter With {.ParameterName = "@STATUS", .DbType = SqlDbType.Char, .Size = 3, .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(oStatus)

        Dim oErr = New iDB2Parameter With {.ParameterName = "@ERROR", .DbType = SqlDbType.Char, .Size = 1, .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(oErr)

        ' return value
        Dim oRetval = New iDB2Parameter With {.ParameterName = "@RETURN_VALUE", .DbType = SqlDbType.Char, .Size = 10, .Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(oRetval)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        model.PO = opo.Value
        model.Approver = oApprover.Value
        model.Status = oStatus.Value
        model.Err = oErr.Value

    End Using
return model
```

So the big question is this:
Why on earth would connection pooling be responsible for out parameter values???
Could this be a bug in the IBM iSeries iDB2Connection implementation?

Comment: I think posting the procedure code might have been more useful.

Comment: I don't have access to the stored proc.  Besides, the stored proc is not the problem.  Once pooling is turned off the PO and Approver return nulls.  Additional calls to the stored proc do not return these cached values.

Comment: If the stored procedure is not a problem, how is it then "a bug in the iSeries implementation"?

Comment: I'm thinking it may be a bug in how IBM implemented the iSeries Database Connection in regards to application pooling.  Why else would recycling IIS application pool affect the output parameters?

Comment: I re-worded Step 3.  I incorrectly indicated I fixed the data.  I also added some further explanation.  This is a complicated problem that has troubled me for months.  I've been waiting for our AS400 team to fix what I thought was their problem with the Stored Procedure.  Thanks for taking the time to read and comment.  
If I do not recycle the app pool Step 3 always results with populated PO and Approver
If I recycle the app pool then the results look like Step 1.

Comment: The IIS application pool is caching stored procedure output parameters by name and returning a cached value when nulls are detected.  This happens with ODBC or iSeries connections.

When I recycled the application pool this cached value went away.   I added to the connection string “pooling=false;” and these cached values would no longer persist.  

I would still like to know why this happens so if anyone has an insight please share what you know.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this deserves to be posted as an answer.

Comment: Fail:  We need to see the  procedure to determine why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My boss asked me to try calling the stored procedure using iSeries Navigator just to see what the out parameters contain.  Boy was I surprised.

It turned out that the Stored Procedure (SP) was at fault after all.  I sat with the AS400 RPG developer this morning and watched them debug the SP.  The problem had to do with uninitialized memory.

Here's the definition of the SP:
BF6360CL(@REQNO, @USER, @ENVIRONMENT, @PO[out], @Approver[out], @Status[out], @Error[out])

[image]

I then reset my connection to the AS400 in iSeries Navigator and the output parameters reset back to 
4 = S2.RETU
5 = RN_VAR0000
etc...

The AS400 developer is making changes now to initialize the variables.  When they're done I expect to be able to change my program back to use connection pooling.

**When I reset the IIS App Pool it reset my connection to the database.  This seemed to release allocated memory on the AS400.**

If anyone has more specifics about Connections and AS400 output parameter memory please share.

Comment: Now that the output variables in the AS400 Stored Procedure are initialized everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The IIS application pool is caching stored procedure output parameters by name and returning a cached value when nulls are detected. This happens with ODBC or iSeries connections. When I recycled the application pool this cached value went away. I added to the connection string “pooling=false;” and these cached values would no longer appear.